# Bash RegEx on OSX Vs Linux (oddities)

Tags: regex, bash

*This is about Bash development and **coding** of portable Bash scripts that use RegEx*.

Using Bash RegEx, on a Mac, I can do this:

```
coconut-mac$ a='bananacoconutman'; [[ "$a" =~ banana(.*?)man ]] && echo FOUND ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
FOUND coconut
```

Nice. Useful in many places. Like.

When I try doing this, it fails:

```
coconut-mac$ a='<title>coconut</title>'; [[ "$a" =~ \<title\>(.*?)\</title\> ]] && echo FOUND ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

The **exact** same command runs *perfectly* on the penguin:

```
coconut-linux$ a='<title>coconut</title>'; [[ "$a" =~ \<title\>(.*?)\</title\> ]] && echo FOUND ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
FOUND coconut
```

- Why?
- How to fix it to make the script portable?

**EDIT**: On the Mac:

```
OS X version: 10.8.2
Bash version: 4.2.37(2)-release
```

on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

```
Linux kernel version: 3.2.0-29-generic-pae
Linux version: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Bash version: 4.2.24(1)-release
```

Comment: What versions of grep are you using on each system? There is no single version of Linux - what flavor/version are you using?

Comment: s/grep/bash/ >.>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my Mac, `info bash / =~ RET` says:

> An additional binary operator, `=~', is available, with the same
>   precedence as`==' and `!='.  When it is used, the string to the
>   right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression
>   and matched accordingly (as in regex3)).

`man 3 regex` says:

> A repetition operator (`?',`*', `+', or bounds) cannot follow another repetition
>   operator.  A repetition operator cannot begin an expression or subexpression or
>   follow`^' or `|'.

I don't see any analogous documentation in GNU regex's `man 3 regex` or `info regex`.

If I remove the `?` from your `(.*?)` and do the following, it works on both OSes:

```
$ a='<title>coconut</title>'; [[ "$a" =~ \<title\>(.*)\</title\> ]] && echo FOUND ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
FOUND coconut
```

Comment: Nice write-up!!

Answer (score 3):

This would probably be the answer:

Default bash on Darwin (10.8.1/2):

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
```

Default bash on, say, Ubuntu 12 LTS:

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Making it portable would be stepping away from newer bash quirks and using things like `sed`, `awk`, whatnot.